# Should I delete my answer

Tags: discussion

This is my answer. https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/150847/69916

The answer by other user is more accurate than mine. I have stated a few 'wrong' statements. I fixed some of them. I can fix the statement which says "i feel it could be an old version of font", but then it would become a copy of the existing answer. Also I'm not sure editing this much is moral or not. Like changing your views about what you earlier thought, later.

So should I delete it as I feel future users might misinterpret it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally my advice would be: delete away if you feel like it shouldn't exist anymore.

**However**, yours is the accepted answer, so it would be problematic to just delete it. The *most honest* thing to do here, I think, is to [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/150847/edit) your answer and put a disclaimer at the top stating the other answer is (probably) more accurate.

It happens. For example on Stack Overflow, where info in answers tends to grow 'stale' or outdated more quickly so the accepted answer is no longer best practice.

Comment: On top, since it’s the accepted answer, Vikas **cannot** delete it.